# As part of developing a tool, I have to extract only flipkart.com or flipkart from the url http://www.flipkart.com

Tags: python

As part of developing a tool, I have to extract only `flipkart.com` or `flipkart` from the URL `http://www.flipkart.com`.

I am writing the code as:

```
filename = dns.name.from_text(url).split(3)[1].to_text(omit_final_dot=True)
```

I am getting the output `flipkart.com\010`. How to extract using Python?

Answer (score 0):

The [tld](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tld) package will help u as:

```
from tld import get_tld
from tld.utils import update_tld_names
update_tld_names()

print get_tld("http://www.flipkart.com")
```

output

> flipkart.com

Comment: following error occured-                                                   TldDomainNotFound: Domain www.flipkart.com didn't match any existing TLD name!

Answer (score 0):

use standard library module [`urlpase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse):

```
In [72]: from urlparse import urlparse

In [73]: flipkart = urlparse("http://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-a6000/p/itme3763q9phgbpn?q=Lenovo A6000&as=on&as- show=on&otracker=start&as-pos=p_1_lenovo&pid=MOBE3762KWZZYZHZ")

In [74]: flipkart.netloc
Out[74]: 'www.flipkart.com'

In [75]: flipkart
Out[75]: ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.flipkart.com', path='/lenovo-a6000/p/itme3763q9phgbpn', params='', query='q=Lenovo A6000&as=on&as- show=on&otracker=start&as-pos=p_1_lenovo&pid=MOBE3762KWZZYZHZ', fragment='')
```

this will return a tuple of 6 components; which corresponds to the general structure of a URL: `scheme://netloc/path;parameters?query#fragment`